# URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:661)>

Tags: python, ssl

I get the error in the title

I have python 2.7.14 and OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017

```
ctx = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS) #Itried all the other protocols
ctx.check_hostname = False #fails with or without these 2 lines
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
resp = urllib2.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
```

Update:
This is the url (sensitive data replaced with ..)
https://www.upwork.com/api/hr/v2/teams/../users.json?oauth_consumer_key=..&oauth_nonce=..&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=..&oauth_token=..&oauth_version=1.0&tz=gmt&oauth_signature=..

All keys and tokens work because I also use them on a javscript platform and they work perfectly there.
Also simply pasting the link in browser works. 
But in python I have no idea how to debug this. Anyone can please help ? Thank you, deeply appreciated

Comment: This is (very likely) not a general behavior with any URL but a behavior with a specific URL. You would need to provide the URL in question so that others can reproduce the problem. Note that protocol version problems can not be bypassed by disabling certificate validation.

Comment: updated. I thought I am missing something about proper way to call with urlopen. I have zero ssl experience and I am on an urgent deadline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ctx = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS) #Itried all the other protocols

There is no `ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS`. There are for example `ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1` which does not work and there is `ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2` which does work for me. Even better use `ssl.create_default_context()`.

Comment: thank you very much for reply Ullrich. I still get the same error with both ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2 and ssl.create_default_context().
Btw if it helps.. the project run for almost a year until I went through the process of getting new authorisation tokens.
I will try and see if installing into a virtual-env helps. Maybe it has something to do with the libraries mixing something..

Comment: @emanuelcristianMocean: are you really getting the same error with TLS 1.2? I get a tls alert protocol version with TLS 1.0 but with TLS 1.2 I get a successful TLS handshake and then a 403 error - because my authentication information are wrong.

Comment: yes. I cannot paste full output in comments but is exactly as before.
I'll try to install a clean copy of python in a virtual machine and get back later.

Comment: clean OS (win7 32bit on a oracle  virtual machine), clean Python 2.7.14, this line still fails with exactly same error: resp = urllib2.urlopen(url,ssl.create_default_context()).read()
If I log the url and copy it to chrome I get the wanted json

Comment: @emanuelcristianMocean: then maybe there is some SSL intercepting firewall fiddling with the connection. Check if you have a proxy configured in the browser. Check also if the browser gets access to the site from the same machine as your Python code. Maybe provide a packet capture (as pcap file) so that one can see what actually happens on the wire.

Comment: I don't think any of those apply because node works . Behind the same firewall as python. And in the virtual machine the only firewall was the windows one. Thank you very much for trying to help Ullrich but I am just going to give up and re-code the application on node.js . I hate to do that but I'd rather do that instead of learning tons of SSL stuff I will not need any time soon.

Comment: Chosen as best answer since you confirmed that the code should work.